# How to change default http port in openstack dashboard?

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am new to OpenStack and I need to change **default http port for dashboard(horizon)** which is currently set to **80**. I've installed/deployed OpenStack using devstack script.

Which configuration files do I need to touch and change?

Obviously, changing only **/etc/apache2/sites-available/horizon.conf** won't do the trick...

Answer (score 3):

Well, just poor me... it was only a matter of **Apache Virtualhost** configuration. I added another **Listen** directive into **ports.conf** file.
Sorry for posting this stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

If you only edit horizon.conf, the change won't last unstack && cleanup && stack.

To make it persistent, edit **/your/devstack/location/files/apache-horizon.template** adding the appropriate Listen directive.

However, you still need to change the Apache listen port, as it listens on 80 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### Centos 7.4, OpenStack Pike & Queens instruction

1. **Change [Puppets module ports file config](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#ports_file) `/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf`**:

   - change line `Listen 80` to `Listen 8888`
2. **Change default host port `/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf`**:

   - change line `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:8888>`
3. **Change Horizon host port `/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-horizon_vhost.conf`**:

   - change line `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:8888>`
4. **Restart `http server`**:

   - `$ systemctl restart httpd.service`
5. **Modify `iptables`**:

   - List the iptables rules with line numbers and remember one with Horizon (`11` in my case)

     ```
     $ iptables -L -n --line-numbers
     [...]
     11 ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 multiport dports 80 /* 001 horizon 80 incoming */
     [...]
     ```
   - Insert the new rule at `11`

     ```
     $ iptables -I INPUT 11 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 8888 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "001 horizon 8888 incoming"
     $ service iptables save
     iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]
     ```
   - Remove the old rule (`11`+1=`12`, check it: `$ iptables -L -n --line-numbers`)

     ```
     $ iptables -D INPUT 12
     $ service iptables save
     iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]
     ```